# Python seems to incorrectly identify case-sensitive string using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, case-sensitive

I'm checking for a case-sensitive string pattern using Python 2.7 and it seems to return an incorrect match. I've run the following tests:

```
>>> import re
>>> rex_str = "^((BOA_[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,3})(?:CO)?.(?i)pdf$)"
>>> not re.match(rex_str, 'BOA_1988-148.pdf')
>>> False
>>> not re.match(rex_str, 'BOA_1988-148.PDF')
>>> False
>>> not re.match(rex_str, 'BOA1988-148.pdf')
>>> True
>>> not re.match(rex_str, 'boa_1988-148.pdf')
>>> False
```

The first three tests are correct, but the final test, 'boa_1988-148.pdf' should return True because the pattern is supposed to treat the first 3 characters (BOA) as case-sensitive.

I checked the expression with an online tester (https://regex101.com/) and the pattern was correct, flagging the final as a no match because the 'boa' was lower case. Am I missing something or do you have to explicitly declare a group as case-sensitive using a case-sensitive mode like (?c)?

Comment: You should switch to Python 3.6+ while you are still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flags do not apply to portions of a regex. You told the regex engine to match case insensitively:

```
(?i)
```

From the the [syntax documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> ```
> (?aiLmsux)
> ```
>
> (One or more letters from the set `'a'`, `'i'`, `'L'`, `'m'`, `'s'`, `'u'`, `'x'`.) The group matches the empty string; the letters set the corresponding flags: `re.A` (ASCII-only matching), `re.I` (ignore case), `re.L` (locale dependent), `re.M` (multi-line), `re.S` (dot matches all), and `re.X` (verbose), ***for the entire regular expression***. (The flags are described in Module Contents.) This is useful if you wish to include the flags as part of the regular expression, instead of passing a flag argument to the `re.compile()` function. Flags should be used first in the expression string.

Emphasis mine, the flag applies to the **whole pattern**, not just a substring. If you need to match just `pdf` or `PDF`, use that in your pattern directly:

```
r"^((BOA_[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,3})(?:CO)?.(?:pdf|PDF)$)"
```

This matches either `.pdf` or `.PDF`. If you need to match any mix of uppercase and lowercase, use:

```
r"^((BOA_[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,3})(?:CO)?.[pP][dD][fF]$)"
```

Answer (score 0):

`(?i)` doesn’t only apply after itself or to the group that contains it. From [the Python 2 `re` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> #### `(?iLmsux)`
>
> (One or more letters from the set `'i'`, `'L'`, `'m'`, `'s'`, `'u'`, `'x'`.) The group matches the empty string; the letters set the corresponding flags […] **for the entire regular expression**.

One option is to do it manually:

```
r"^(BOA_[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,3})(?:CO)?\.[Pp][Dd][Ff]\Z"
```

Another is to use a separate case-sensitive check:

```
 rex_str = r"(?i)^(BOA_[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,3})(?:CO)?\.pdf\Z"
 match = re.match(rex_str, s) if s.startswith("BOA_") else None
```

or separate case-insensitive one:

```
 rex_str = r"^(BOA_[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,3})(?:CO)?\..{3}\Z"
 match = re.match(rex_str, s) if s.lower().endswith(".pdf") else None
```